# How to add an extension method to .Net assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I am new to software development and may be I am asking a very silly question but, I am curious to learn more on this thing.
Is it possible to add an extension method to .Net assembly? I want my extension method to work on every project I am working on. Apart from referencing to my own assembly, is there any other way?

If it is not possible, please explain taking some time.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No. Not possible. Especially not for the .NET framework where the assembliesa re digitally signed.

Comment: No you can't, the .Net assemblies are pre compiled, you don't compile them every time. And imagine the chaos if everyone could extend .Net in that manner

Comment: You can add extension methods to *classes/structs* (assemblies *don't* have methods)

Comment: Interesting to see everybody is getting down voted including me, except a single user :D

Comment: I guess tht person is downvoting everybody @kunichhua2 :))

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of adding methods to an existing assembly.

There's no other way than creating it in your own assembly and referencing that.

Comment: Can you please spend little more time to explain. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @kunichhua2 - there's nothing more to explain. You clearly know how to define an extension method, you can even add it to any namespace you want, however there's no way to physically add that method to an existing .NET assembly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new project as a dll (class library)
2. Add your extention classes/methods to this dll
3. Reference this dll in your future projects

---

In response to your comment, you cannot modify the .net framework, only build your own dll's to include methods you wish to share between projects.

The reason you cannot modify the framework is because the code has been compiled already.

Comment: It's a few years later, but this works well, and is an effective answer to the question. In order to build extension methods for a class into a library usable both by .NET Core and UWP applications, you can put the extension methods in a "Class Library (Universal Windows)" project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create extensible method in class but not possible in your reference dll 
please check here extensible [class method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733816%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

**Is it possible to add an extension method to .Net assembly?**
this itself says that you have to create your own methods to extend .Net assembly which are already deployed. The only way to use is define your own methods and include the namespace in the code where you will use these extenssion methods.

sample. of Extenssion methods.

```
using system;
namespace myNamespace
{
      public static class MyExtMethods
       {
    public static string Foo(this string bar)
           {
             return bar+ "Some values added. ";

           }
        }
}
```

Uses of Extenssion Method.

```
using system;
using myNamespace;
    namespace myNamespace2
    {
          public class Program
           {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
               {
                string str ="Some Value";
               Console.WriteLine(str.Foo());

               }
            }
    }
```